# 1989 Ford Econovan - clutch issues

Tags: ford, clutch

I have a 1989 ford econovan and this morning when i got in the clutch fully depressed with no resistance. I parked it 4 days ago and had no issues while driving. The van starts up fine, but will not go in gear. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How's the clutch fluid reservoir level?